# When do I formally "Own" an app from App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

I'm new to this community. I have some simple question but I can't understand why nobody else ever asked them with below scenario.

**My Scenario**

- As all we know, sometimes developers make their paid apps, **free for a limited time**.
- I unfortunately  have a Limited internet in home.

*** What I do in this situation is that I "Get" this temporary free apps, and after about 1% of downloading I pause them in order to resume downloading later. ***

---

Notice that all below questions are related to each other like a chain and It's not sensible to ask in three separate question.

**My Questions:**

1. When I formally "***own***" an app (if it's free or paid)? right after pushing the "Get" button in App Store **OR** when downloading has completed ?
2. (According to above story) Can I resume this downloads (also when apps get back to paid mode) ?
3. If this temporary free apps become paid again, Will I still get new updates for ever since I own them ?

**PS:** when somebody "*purchase*" a paid app, he is "*owner*" of that app. In this question I used word "*own*" in the meaning of "*possession*".

Comment: Haha. As if you could "own" any software you didn't write yourself anymore. It's just a tangled web of licenses and temporary rights to use these days.

Comment: I'm tempted to close this for several reasons. 1) We strongly prefer one question per question. 2) Ownership is a legal framework, and the more precise you are about jurisdiction, the less useful this is for the site. The less precise you are about jurisdiction, the less useful someone's generalized answer is. What is your definition of "own"

Comment: @bmike (1) asking several coherence question is usual in stackoverflow.com and I don't think it is always bad things (2) In my literature,  word "own" means "purchase" and means you can get updates in future.

Comment: @Emadpres We aren't SO - we **close all manner of questions that are a good fit for SO**. We prefer individual questions with individual answers. Once you have done the piecemeal work, asking a "synthesis" question is just fine since you are asking how to chain things together. As to your definition, you don't get any updates unless a) the app developer ships one and b) apple approves it. There's simply no implied contract in any App Store terms and conditions, so perhaps your main premise of "ownership" itself is faulty?

Comment: SO does close questions that require more than one different answer - if you have left some you have been luck. Quest and answers only work if there is only one question - how do you accept the correct answer if one part is in one answer and the other in another

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Once you tap Get, then confirm it by tapping again, then entering your Apple ID or using Touch ID, and the download starts, then you own it.

   The download starting is important—if there's not enough space on the device, or the network disconnects first, or anything else prevents the circular progress bar from starting, you don't own the app.

   Once download has started, you can tap the Stop button to stop the download. The icon changes to an iCloud download icon and you now own the app.
2. You can download apps you own from the Purchases list found at the top of the Updates tab on iOS.
3. Once the app has been added to your Apple ID, the app will remain on the list regardless of whether the app developer changes the price tier of the app. It won't be removed if the price increases and you can't be charged in the future.

   This also applies with part 2, as if you purchase the app, then delete it, you can download it again without being charged even if the price tier increases.

Comment: re 3) What happens if the app is removed from the app store?

Comment: @Mark You can no longer download the app from the App Store. Unless you have a backup, the .ipa or you are jailbroken, you can no longer install the app.

Comment: @grgarside You can download apps that have been removed from the App Store via the Purchases list, but you just can't see the app page. Assuming you have downloaded/purchased the app before it was removed.

Comment: @MacMac This used to be true, but not any more? Flappy Bird is gone from my list of purchases, for example?

Comment: I think this answer over-simplifies things. A developer can pull an app from purchased. Apple can pull apps from purchased. Running apps that have been pulled isn't something that Apple systematically blocks, but they can do that technically and perhaps legally. Even possession isn't ownership if the OS won't trust an expired or invalidated code signature. Just because you have an IPA backed up to iTunes and otherwise can side-load apps via USB - there are hoops to jumped before iOS will run an app.

Comment: @bmike This isn't about the legalities of app purchasing…? I understand Apple can pull apps and etc, but this Q&A is just about when exactly the app is added to your Apple ID, not about whether you 'legally own the code' or some other higher order control?

Comment: Yes. The question is far worse than your attempt to answer. The problem with overly broad questions is exemplified by your attempt to tie together good experience and facts. I see no practical problem the OP is trying to solve with the "when do I own it" premise...

Comment: @bmike I can't understand why you're insisting on saying that my question is faulty. I asked a question which really is meaningful to me and others and somebody has answered it as I wish and in a sensible manner and my problem get solved with that answer. please excuse me for my bad English and using wrong words please.

Comment: @Emadpres let's discuss what makes a good question on [meta]

Comment: @Emadpres I really like your question. If this gets discussed on meta, I'd appreciate a ping.